# How to configure kafka-console-consumer to read a single message and quit?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to configure the `kafka-console-consumer` to read a single message from a topic and then quit?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `--max-messages=1`

If you just run `kafka-console-consumer` alone you can see the description of this flag